# Date not valid for month specified

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem when running this Oracle SQL statement:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tbl_content
 WHERE last_updated >= (systimestamp - INTERVAL '1' month(1)) 
 ORDER BY last_updated desc
```

And this error:

```
    java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:111)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:330)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:287)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:742)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:212)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:951)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1053)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:835)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1123)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3284)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3328)
    at com.vtdd.sms.content.xskt.XsktService.getKQXSFollowArea(XsktService.java:4044)
    at com.vtdd.sms.content.xskt.XsktService.getMessages(XsktService.java:421)
    at com.vht.sms.content.ContentAbstract.getSubmitMessages(ContentAbstract.java:47)
    at com.vht.sms.content.ContentFactory.getSubmitMessages(ContentFactory.java:335)
    at com.vht.sms.content.ContentFactory.run(ContentFactory.java:62)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Could you tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, why are you using `systimestamp`? If you want this to the month then surely `sysdate` is exact enough? Secondly, I like - i.e. it's personal preference - to make it extremely clear what's happening. Oracle has an [`add_months`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/add_months.php) function, which will do what you want. So your query could easily be:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tbl_content
 WHERE last_updated >= add_months(sysdate, -1) 
 ORDER BY last_updated desc
```

Answer (score 4):

What is actually wrong is that [interval arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00208) doesn't adjust days - see the 6th bullet in the link:

> When interval calculations return a datetime value, the result must be an actual datetime value or the database returns an error.

[`ADD_MONTHS`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/functions011.htm) does; as that link says:

> If date is the last day of the month or if the resulting month has fewer days than the day component of date, then the result is the last day of the resulting month.

So, `ADD_MONTHS(DATE '2011-12-31', -1)` gives you 2011-11-30, while `DATE '2011-12-31' - INTERVAL '1' MONTH` tries to give you 2011-11-31, which as the message says, isn't a valid date.

(It's debatable if this behaviour is actually wrong; it's unexpected, but I believe it's conforming to ANSI. There may be times you want it to work this way, though I can't think of any...)